# Jenkins global build timeout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How do i abort jobs that have been waiting for nodes that don't exist. These currently are waiting forever.

There are no nodes with the label ‘xxxx’

I have https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin configured but it does not seem to stop these. any other way? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to kill Jobs that can't find an agent with the provided label.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { job ->
      job.getBuilds().each { b ->        
        if(b.isInProgress()) {
           if(b.getLog().contains("There are no nodes with the label")){
                println "Build: " + b.getNumber() + " of Job: " +  job.getName() + " is Waiting. Hence Killing!!!"
                b.doKill()
           }
        } 
   }  
}
```

---

**Update**

Check if the waiting time is greater than a threshold.

```
def waitThreshold = 300 // In seconds

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { job ->
      job.getBuilds().each { b ->     
        if(b.isInProgress()) {
           def waitTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - b.getStartTimeInMillis())/1000;
           println "Build: " + b.getNumber() + " is Idling for : " + waitTime
           if(b.getLog().contains("There are no nodes with the label") && waitTime > waitThreshold){
                println "Build: " + b.getNumber() + " of Job: " +  job.getName() + " is Waiting. Hence Killing!!!"
                b.doKill()
           }
        } 
   }  
}
```

Comment: no, i only want to kill jobs waiting for label for x amount of time

Comment: @pa1 It's a minor modification to the code ;) CHeck the updated answer.